# What is the diffrence between clear and unset in backbone?

Tags: backbone.js

*I am new in backnone, and I just think the title is clear what is my question but I ask it again:*

What is the diffrent between **clear** and **unset** in backbone? (both of them return one thing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-`unset` removes an attribute from the model.

> unsetmodel.unset(attribute, [options])
>
> Remove an attribute by
>   deleting it from the internal attributes hash. Fires a "change" event
>   unless silent is passed as an option.

-`clear` removes all attributes from the model.

> clearmodel.clear([options])
>
> Removes all attributes from the model,
>   including the id attribute. Fires a "change" event unless silent is
>   passed as an option.

http://backbonejs.org/